# Inserting a partial row or change from fixed width to ragged right maintaining columns

Tags: ssis

I'll admit I made a mistake and am trying to avoid extra work. I have what I thought was a fixed width file where every record is 1332 spaces comprising of ~150 columns. I import it into a sql table with an SSIS package which is fixed width, except for the very last record which is only 1330 spaces. The last column is string type and normally 4 spaces but for the last record it is 2, but I also don't care about it and uncheck it in the flat file source. I believe it's not importing that last record because of the shorter width, which I could fix by making it ragged right, but that would wipe out all the columns I've defined.

Is it possible to tweak some setting so it'll import that last record or change to a ragged right without having to redefine all my columns?

Here is a simple example of how the file is formatted. Note the 2 spaces at the last record.

```
'555-1234  @À555-2345  @À555-3456,è@™555-4567  @À555-5678  '
```

Possible work around, can you add two spaces to the last line of the incoming flat file source data without modifying the actual file?

Comment: I'm willing to wager, the difference in length is the final row does not have the "hidden" characters carriage return and line feed (cr/lf, ascii 10/13). If that's the case, look at your Export process that builds the output and maybe you can fix the format from that process and re-use what you already have.

Comment: Sort of. Each record is separated by some random special characters. Most of the time it's '  @À' but sometimes it's something like '{Ä@À' or 'CR/LF@™" but it's always 4 characters, except for the last line it's only 2 blank spaces.